# string is printing in a wrong character .i.e. python interpreter is taking string in a wrong way

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am new to python.Following is code I am not able to get the correct the string i just want to get the string till date in the following code:

```
def ExtractMail():
    mailString=str(".\\Attachments\Treated\2026-11-22\ISCD\ACCEPT-A350")
    print mailString
    index=mailString.rfind("\\",0,(mailString.rfind("\\")-1))
    print index
    print mailString[0:index]
ExtractMail()
```

Output that i am getting is this:

```
.\Attachments\Treated�6-11-22\ISCD\ACCEPT-A350
29
.\Attachments\Treated�6-11-22
```

The output I am looking for

`.\Attachments\Treated\2016-11-22\ISCD\ACCEPT-A350
29
.\Attachments\Treated\2016-11-22`

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after, but you should probably escape your backslashes. `\ ` will escape the following character, in this case `\2` will escape the number "2". Try `\\` for each backslash. Also, if you could edit your question to include the desired output (what you want the string to look like, that would be nice).

Comment: `202` is being treated as octal value.

Comment: yeah i know issue but i unable to find the solution for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `r` in front of the string to treat string as it is:

```
def ExtractMail():
    mailString=str(r".\\Attachments\Treated\2026-11-22\ISCD\ACCEPT-A350")
    print mailString
    index=mailString.rfind("\\",0,(mailString.rfind("\\")-1))
    print index
    print mailString[0:index]
ExtractMail()
```

Output will be:

```
.\\Attachments\Treated\2026-11-22\ISCD\ACCEPT-A350
33
.\\Attachments\Treated\2026-11-22
```

EDIT: If this string comes as variable from some function (lets call this function `f_out`), You can do:

```
def ExtractMail():
    mailString=str("%r" % f_out())
    print mailString
    index=mailString.rfind("\\",0,(mailString.rfind("\\")-1))
    print index
    print mailString[0:index]
ExtractMail()
```

Comment: and what if i am getting mailString as an parameter of the function

Comment: i have tried what you have said but still getting same output on printing

Comment: Updated the answer. You should use `%r` instead of `r"{}".format()` syntax.

Comment: i am getting output after using %r is "'.\\Attachments\\Treated\x816-11-22\\ISCD\\ACCEPT-A350'"

Comment: Sorry, missed this somehow. After some digging, found out that this is not possible. When You get string from some function, it is already interpreted, and You can't return it back to it's original state.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape backslashes in [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html):

```
mailString = ".\\Attachments\\Treated\\2026-11-22\\ISCD\\ACCEPT-A350"
```

Comment: sorry i can't do that actually this string will come to me in a variable as a parameter to the function